# Input.GetAxisRaw not working? not moving horizontal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public float movespeed = 0.0f;
public float maxmovespeed = 30f;

private Vector3 input;
private CharacterController controller;

void Update () {

    input = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, 0);        
    controller.Move (Vector3.forward * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.magnitude < maxmovespeed) {        
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (input * movespeed);
    }
}
```

i want my player to keep moving forward which it does but its not moving left and right. there are no errors. i suspect its a logic flaw but i can't figure it out.

Comment: You are using CharacterController and Rigidbody. You have to choose one or the other as they somehow do related things and will not work together. The latest CharacterController from Std Assets actually makes use of Rigidbody so maybe you wan to look into it.

Comment: yeah thanks for the info :)
i fixed it by using controller